# .NET type menu in HTML, PHP and CSS

Tags: php, html, css, .net

It's pretty weird to create menu in HTML and CSS. We need a lot of coding to do it. is there any way to use the .NET's menu in HTML, PHP like including a plugin. (so that it has .NET menu's features like 1) pressing esc to exit menu, 2)assign shortcut to open a particular menu

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) is this link has anything to do with it

Comment: .NET Type menu? Which menu is that? Are you sure it's not a script based menu seeing as you mention pressing esc does something which seems to indicate client side code?

Comment: i just know to create menu in .NET and its cool, like wise i searched for any plugin to create painless menu in php

Comment: Can you show some of the ".NET menu" code?

Comment: no code, in toolbox i just drag n drop menu strip

Comment: Then it's a menu for Windows Forms (applications) and not for web pages.

Comment: when i searched http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dotnet.php here, php has windows extensions (.NET), thats y i asked for a plugin like that

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Please don't try to confuse the OP into thinking they're seeing things, just because they can't provide proof that there is a [Menu control in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

.NET is not a real web technology (except for MVC). It has been made to facilitate the transition between heavy and web technology.

If you check in the output code (generated)  in the browser you ll see that code lines are as numerous as Php/css

More over you'll see that the ouput is html/css [and javascript]. Once complied, IIS only translate the hard code to text understandable by the browser